# Docker on windows - certificate error

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-registry, docker-machine

When I try to build or run a docker container, e.g.:

`docker build -t docker.example.com/research/example_project .`

It leads to following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.513 MB
Step 1 : FROM docker.example.com/research/example_project:latest
unable to ping registry endpoint https://docker.example.com/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://docker.example.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://docker.example.com/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

All workaround I found on google are for ubuntu, but this case is when docker is running on windows 8 (virtual machine is installed).

Comment: Maybe a silly question but the https://docker.example.com/v2/ registry existis and you're able to authenticate to the registry?

Comment: I got the solution. Had to add registry in insecure registry list.

Comment: @xavi, could you please explain what you mean by
"Had to add registry in insecure registry list" ? That way you might help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pre-1.12 Docker version for Windows (the one that uses VirtualBox with Boot2Docker), you need to add your registry certificate to the Boot2Docker virtual machine. From your Docker console window, type:

```
$ docker-machine ssh default
$ DOMAIN_NAME=<type your domain name here>:5000
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/$DOMAIN_NAME
$ sudo vi /etc/docker/certs.d/$DOMAIN_NAME/ca.crt

--> then copy certificate text in there and save (type :wq)
```

The next step is creating a script that adds the certificate to a list of allowed certificates:

```
$ sudo touch /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh && sudo chmod +x /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
$ sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
```

Then fill in the "your domain name" variable below and paste this script in the file you just created:

```
#!/bin/bash
CA_CERTS_DIR=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
DOCKER_CERTS_DOMAIN_DIR=/etc/docker/certs.d/<your domain name>
CERTS_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
CAFILE=${CERTS_DIR}/ca-certificates.crt

cp ${DOCKER_CERTS_DOMAIN_DIR}/ca.crt ${CA_CERTS_DIR}


for cert in $(/bin/ls -1 ${DOCKER_CERTS_DOMAIN_DIR}); do
SRC_CERT_FILE=${CA_CERTS_DIR}/${cert}
CERT_FILE=${CERTS_DIR}/${cert}
HASH_FILE=${CERTS_DIR}/$(/usr/local/bin/openssl x509 -noout -hash -in ${SRC_CERT_FILE} 2>/dev/null)

[ ! -L ${CERT_FILE} ] && /bin/ln -fs ${SRC_CERT_FILE} ${CERT_FILE}

for idx in $(/usr/bin/seq 0 9); do
if [ -L ${HASH_FILE}.${idx} ]; then
[ "$(/usr/bin/readlink ${HASH_FILE}.${idx})" = "${SRC_CERT_FILE}" ] && break
else
/bin/ln -fs ${SRC_CERT_FILE} ${HASH_FILE}.${idx}
break
fi
done
/bin/cat ${SRC_CERT_FILE} >> ${CAFILE}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Docker >= 1.12 for Windows (the one that runs native and uses Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox), you can add the host address of your registry as an "insecure registry" to the Docker daemon config:

Right click Docker icon in your system tray --> Settings... --> click the 'Docker Daemon' tab --> change the line

```
"insecure-registries": [
  ],
```

into

```
"insecure-registries": [
"your.domain.com:5000"
  ],
```

This allowed me to access my private registry again using the new Docker for Windows. Probably works for Mac too, but haven't tested.